# Turn Off Caching for fabricjs image object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, caching, fabricjs

I am trying to load an image using fabricjs using the function:
fabric.Image.fromURL()

I want to turn off caching because when the image is updated, the fabricjs image object doesn't get updated because it gets cached.

I cannot use a random string as a dummy parameter in the url to stop caching because the url I am using contains a signature parameter and therefore if I try to add a dummy parameter I need to update the signature parameter of the url which is something I don't want to do.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Running into the same thing right now.

Answer (score 4):

Since version 1.7.0 fabricjs is not caching Images. This is from documentation.

> objectCaching :Boolean When `true`, object is cached on an additional
>   canvas. default to false for images since 1.7.0

Please check [fabricjs image](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html) documentation

I know it is too late, but maybe somebody can update their library to newer one.

Comment: now your answer is old, it became true by default not false